# SFTP with ssh - restrict access to home directory form only some users

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, privileges

I have SFTP access to my server using SSH. At the moment, I am accessing the server trough ssh with 2 users: www-data and public_user.

Everything works fine, but the problem is when I am trying to restrict the access for public_user to his home directory only through SFTP.

For that, I added public_user to the group sftponly and changed the sshd_config:

```
 Match group sftponly
 ChrootDirectory %h
 X11Forwarding no
 AllowTcpForwarding no
 ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 73
```

Once the ssh reloaded, I have access to my home directory with public_user but the access through ssh with the user www-data is blocked.

Any idea how to distinguish those two users, so that public_user has access to his home dir only and the www-data can connect normally trough ssh and work on any www-data dir.

Thank you.

Comment: A -1, please advise!!!

Comment: I guess this has been already answered in below link http://askubuntu.com/questions/196062/sftp-permission-denied-on-files-owned-by-www-data If you have any specific doubts that are not covered above, update here to assist.

Answer (score 1):

Also answered here: https://askubuntu.com/a/206376.  Looks like the main thing you might be missing is that you have to have the home directory of the jailed user (public_user) owned by root.  Is your user "www-data" in the sftpgroup; it shouldn't be.  Or else do a `Match User public_user` instead of `Match Group`.